# SQLITE Complex select statement. Help me speed it up

Tags: database, sqlite

Some may or may not consider this a complex statement, but for me (since I've only been doing statement for about a month) this one is.  The below statement returns me the exact results I am looking for, but my problem is that it take over 95 seconds to run on a iMac.  I need this statement to run on an iPhone. Can anyone thing of a better (quicker) way to do this?

```
select categories.category  
from categories join categories_listings 
where categories_listings.category_id = categories.id
  and categories.association_id = 1 
  and (select count(*) 
       from (select (
                    select categories.category 
                    from categories left join categories_listings 
                    where categories_listings.category_id = categories.id
                      and categories.association_id = 1 
                      and listings.id = categories_listings.listing_id) as region 
             from listings left join chamber_specifics
               on chamber_specifics.listing_id=listings.id 
             where region = categories.category  
               and listings.association_id=1 
               and listings.status = 1 
               and downtown='Y')) >0 
group by categories.category;
```

Let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: After trying to edit that monstrosity I'd say: yes, it's complex.  Your first `join` doesn't have an `ON` clause... I don't think you need that `count(*)` clause - just select all records and do an `IN` check.

Comment: Sorry for the monstrosity.  I appreciate your input.  I'm reworking it right now to include an ON clause and do an IN check.  I'll let you know how it turns out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a statement that gets me the same results as in my question, but much fast at about 0.062 seconds to complete.  Below is my Statement:  (Thanks Rudu for the direction!)

```
select (
        select categories.category 
        from categories left join categories_listings 
        where categories_listings.category_id = categories.id  
        and categories.association_id = 1 
        and listings.id = categories_listings.listing_id) as region 
  from listings left join chamber_specifics 
    on chamber_specifics.listing_id=listings.id 
  where  listings.association_id=1 
  and listings.status = 1   
  and downtown='Y' 
group by region
```